# Can i fit a 26 x 1.5 tyre to my wheel?

Tags: tire

I have a Hybrid bike that has 26 x 1.95 tyres fitted, they are knobbly's and I want to change them for road tyres, I have seen a make that I like but it is a 26 x 1.5 Will i be able to fit them to my bike. 
Thank You

Comment: With only a few exceptions, any 26" tire whose width is expressed in a *decimal fraction* (ie, with a "decimal point" rather than a "slash") will fit a wheel whose width is similarly expressed, so long as the width mismatch is not incredibly great.

Comment: @DanielRHicks How much is "incredibly great"? In this case, the proposed tyre is 23% narrower.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - It depends on how the rim was sized, of course.  Most BSOs use fairly narrow rims, but some fancier bikes may have wider ones.  I have little doubt that a 1.5" inch tire would fit most rims that originally carried 1.95, but it's hard to say how close to "ideal" it would be.  It gets to be a red flag when the rim is actually wider than the widest part of the mounted tire.

Answer (score 7):

According to my handy-dandy tire/wheel compatibility chart, if your rim is between 17-24.9mm Inside Rim Width, that tire should work fine with your wheel.

Comment: i know the guy that made that chart :P

Comment: Hey me too lol!